# Problem showing when trying to do an update on my Xiaomi

Tags: android, xiaomi

When I try to make an update on my android It display me this error.

```
java.lang.illegalargumentexception:Unknown URL 
content://downloads/my_downloads
  at
android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:2189)
  at
android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:2155)
  at
android.app.DownloadManager.enqueue(DownloadManager.java:1668)
  at com.android.updater.j.a(SourceFile:1036)
  at com.android.updater.j.b(SourceFile:636)
  at com.android.updater.j.a(SourceFile:36)
  at com.android.updater.j$2.run(SourceFile:643)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Was expecting the update to start
But
It crashes as soon as i click on the button and display me the rapport

Comment: Seems like this is the error: java.lang.illegalargumentexception:Unknown URL 
content://downloads/my_downloads. Can you share the code from where this logic is enacted?

Comment: How can I do that. My phone is like bricked I can't open any app except the settings and a weird notification is staying in my notification bar saying "Finishing system update..." and it's been 15 hours that it's freezed

Comment: What type of "update" are you talking about? A system update, an update of your own app or a third party app? How do you try to perform the update?